PHP Proxy Redirecting / Page Change Logic Needed
I’ve been trying to make a web proxy using PHP and I always come to the same problem. When the user gets redirected on the proxied page or the page changes, it applies it to my proxy's site.
localhost:3000/?url=https://example.com/example
This is what we want
localhost:3000/example
This is what we get.
Here is my code:
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['url'])) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
  echo 'Missing URL parameter';
  exit;
}

$url = $_GET['url'];

if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
  echo 'Invalid URL';
  exit;
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$content_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
$content_length = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD);

curl_close($ch);

if ($http_code !== 200) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 ' . $http_code);
  echo 'Failed to fetch the content';
  exit;
}

$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$headers = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
$body = substr($response, $header_size);

foreach (explode("\r\n", $headers) as $header) {
  if (!empty($header) && stripos($header, 'Content-Length') === false && stripos($header, 'Transfer-Encoding') === false) {
    header($header);
  }
}

header('Content-Type: ' . $content_type);

if ($content_length > 0) {
  header('Content-Length: ' . $content_length);
}

echo $body;
?>

How can I write logic for this?
